# How to convert SQL to diagram

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, diagram

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and postgresql,

I have a old postgresql code, but I don't have the diagram, the code is correct, and work's well, but I need update the system.

How can I convert a sql code to diagram (relations between tables)?

Comment: What kind of "diagram" do you expect from a SQL query?

Comment: Diagram about relations between tables... I edit the post with this information...

Comment: https://www.pgmodeler.com.br - it have reverse engineering function (however in my installation it stops on 9.4 PG version) But I feeling that you want something another... (something like [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)) You really should to clarify what you mean by "postgresql code" and by "diagram".